# C++ : vector of vector and cache locality

Tags: c++, vector, cache-locality

I am looking for a library/solution that will alleviate the rather important number of cache miss I am experiencing in my program

```
class Foo{
    std::vector<Foo*> myVec;

    // Rest of the class
};

int main(){
     // Some code
     std::vector<Foo*> myVecOfFoo;
}
```

So, the first thing I did was to create a `std::vector<Foo>` and every single `Foo*` points toward this vector. It helped a lot. **My main issue is with `std::vector<Foo*> myVec;`**. Each one of these vectors' internal array is located in a different part of the memory. In the same way that I created a single `std::vector<Foo>` so that all my `Foo` are contiguous in memory, I would like all my `std::vector<Foo*> myVec;` to be aligned in memory (Actually, the internal arrays). How?

Notes : An important point is that the size of `myVec` varies between instances of `Foo`. Otherwise I could trivially build a single `std::vector<Foo*>` and write getters/setters. Also, I have `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` instead of `Foo*` because I am not a savage, but it makes the understanding of the example easier. Finally, I guarantee that the ownership forms a DAG, so I don't have cycles in my shared pointers.

Comment: Hmmm, getting contiguous memory might be difficult with variable sizing. I would maybe look into arena allocation if it is that important.

Comment: One thing I can think of is to use a custom allocator that stores all the data together in memory.  Doing so though limits how many `Foo`'s you can have.

Comment: have a look at boost's [small_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html)

Comment: Isn't there a hint command for the vector such that it keeps size within hint boundaries or just forces its parent class to extend?

Comment: If you don't know the maximum number of instances of `Foo` then you will have to consider what happens when you need to grow your contiguous storage to accommodate new instances. Any naive implementation will invalid all references, iterators and pointers to all instances of `Foo`. An additional complication occurs when destroying instances of `Foo` out of order, leaving holes your in your storage (if this matters). Perhaps a proxy class can be used, storing the *index* of the `Foo` instance, but then you introduce a new level of indirection that might not be acceptable.

Comment: Is your structure static, in the sense that you can build it once, and then "freeze", or does your program go though the graph, and makes modifications?

Comment: @sp2danny : I thought about it, but now all my `Foo`s are different classes (depending on the size of the vector). @Francois : excellent points, which make me seriously reconsider doing it. @dasblinkenlight : Unfortunately yes, I keep on making changes

Answer (score 3):

Replace `std::vector<Foo*>` with a pair of

```
std::vector<Foo*>::const_iterator begin;
std::vector<Foo*>::const_iterator end;
```

Make a single `std::vector<Foo*>`, and place all pointers into it. Then parcel out contiguous blocks of pointers to individual instances of `Foo` by setting their `begin` and `end` iterators.

This may require a preprocessing step, when you build your graph with `std::vector<Foo*>` from instances of a "node" class, e.g.

```
class FooNode {
    Foo *myFoo;
    std::vector<Foo*> myVec;
};
```

Once your nodes are connected, walk through the graph, and collect `myVec`s into one big vector. Once you are done with all individual vectors, walk the preliminary graph again, and set `begin` and `end` positions into `myFoo`s. You can compute positions by adding the size of `FooNode`'s vector to the current position. This will work, as long as your walks through the graph are identical.

Comment: I really liked this answer, but Francois Andrieux mentionned that if I ever add items in the `std::vector<Foo*>` beyond the capacity, every single iterator is invalidated

Comment: @Fezvez That's right! This is precisely the reason why your structure must remain static after the preprocessing step is over. I added more specifics about constructing the graph from `FooNode`s, which postpones taking iterators from the vector until you are sure that there are going to be no further modifications.